# CSS line-height not affecting float:right element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two span elements that I'm trying to vertically center and I've managed to center the left element by matching the line-height with the height of the parent element however the right element which has a style of float:right is not affected by the line-height change, is there any reason for this and how can I vertically center the floated element too?

HTML

```
<div class='panel panel-default remove-radius slideshow-holder'>
    <span id='slideshow_prev_button' class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></span>
    <span id='slideshow_next_button' class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right float-right'></span>
    <div class='panel-body'>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slideshow-holder
{
    background:url('../res/images/abwallpaper.jpg');
    height:300px;
    line-height:300px;
}
```

Note: I'm also using bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just element's inline content is affected by setting `line-height`. Floated element is `block`, that's the reason why `line-height` doesn't work you.

Set `line-height` to arrows, not to a wrapper. I set `float` to both `span`s, when you set `float: right` to the second one and left arrow stays as an `inline` element, next arrow will be a few pixels lower.

```
.slideshow-holder {
    background:url('../res/images/abwallpaper.jpg');
    height:300px;
}

.slideshow-holder span {float: left; line-height: 300px;}
#slideshow_next_button {float: right;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cnntwodL/1/

Comment: this works great and my arrows are centered vertically. One thing though, I had given my arrows a border radius to try and create a circle as a sort of background, however the line-height is stretching them out: http://i.imgur.com/vF02Vjd.png Is there anyway to preserve the circle and keep them vertically centered? CSS for circles:   #slideshow_prev_button, #slideshow_next_button
{
 padding:20px;
 border-radius:20px;
 background:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 border:2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
}